# subscibe from Model state in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can i subscribe to /gazebo/model_states ? Sorry, i am a beginner an did not understand it, yet.I read the tutorial but it does not help me.I want to get the x,y and z Position of my model. For beginning i write this.But how to go on ?

```
ros::Subscriber xyz_subscriber_;

void ModelStatecallback(const gazebo_msgs::ModelStates::ConstPtr& msg)
{


}

xyz_subscriber_ = node_handle_.subscribe</gazebo/model_states>("currentposition", 1, ModelStatecallback);
```

};

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29197/subscibe-from-model-state-in-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a look at the tutorials [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-03-06**:
hi, i read that tutorial, but i dont understand,wheter the topicname is a standard name or just free created?it would be very helpful to understand this stuff ,by explaning me at this special example.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-03-06**:
The topic names are set by the nodes that host those topics. Gazebo defines its own topic names, and you must subscribe to them. If you look in the documentation for any node, it lists the services and topics that it hosts and how to use them.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-09**:
link is broken now.

**Comment by [Dayo](https://answers.ros.org/users/70636/dayo/) on 2021-04-27**:
Here is the correct link: https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the topic you need to subscribe to is listed [here](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo).  In this case, you probably want to do something like below:

```
xyz_subscriber_ = node_handle_.subscribe("/gazebo/model_states", 10, ModelStatecallback);
```

hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2